# Callback function socket.io + node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

There are a client and server side code:

**Client:**

```
socket.on('connect',  function() {
        showSystemMessage('Connected.');

        socket.emit('setuser', wm, function(data){
            console.log(data);
            socket.emit('whoisonline', wm, function(data){
                getOnlineFriends(data);
            });
        });
    });
```

**Server:**

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        socket.on('setuser', function (data, cb) {
            cb(data);
        });
});
```

I get error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function on line 18

**Line 18:**

```
socket.on('setuser', function (data, cb) {
     cb(data); // Line 18
});
```

Then i tried your solution, I got:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function in line 35

socket.on('whoisonline', function (data, cb) {
            redis.sinter('user.friend:' + data.id, 'onlineusers', function(error, intersection) {

                friends.online = intersection;
                friends.total  = intersection.length;

                if(friends.total > 0){
                    intersection.forEach(function(entry) {
                        var socketid = clients[entry];
                        io.sockets.connected[socketid].emit('in', { id : data.id, total : friends.total });
                    });
                }

                cb(friends); // Line 35
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case the following works:

- at the server side

  ```
  socket.on('setuser', (name, cb) => { cb(name); });
  ```
- at the client side

  ```
  socket.emit('setuser', 'user data', r => { console.log(r); });
  ```

Comment: Thanks this is handy.

Answer (score 0):

Socket.io doesn't work with callbacks, you have to work with .emit() and .on(). In this case your source code would look like:

**Client:**

```
socket.on('connect',  function() {
        showSystemMessage('Connected.');

        socket.emit('setuser', wm);
        socket.on("setuser", function(data){
            console.log(data);
            socket.emit('whoisonline', wm);
            socket.on("whoisonline", function(data) { 
                getOnlineFriends(data);
            });
        });
    });
```

**Server:**

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        socket.on('setuser', function (data) {
            socket.emit("setuser", data);
        });
});
```

Comment: Hm, thank you, seems work, but I get callback againn after rewrite on your code. Edited question

Comment: @AhmedFaud Replace line 35 with `socket.emit("whoisonline", friends);`

Comment: We use socket.io with callbacks all the time. It works fine.

Comment: @JeremyTM hmm you seem to be right, I must've missed that 5 years ago.